# errors in my xml

Tags: android

Create xml file and get an error

Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:

```
<linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/buttonlayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:height="32dp" android:gravity="left|top" android:background="#2B60DE" android:paddingtop="2dp" android:paddingbottom="2dp">

    <linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <textview android:id="@+id/txtTest" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textstyle="bold" android:textcolor="#FFFFFF" android:text="@string/app_header" android:textsize="15sp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingleft="5dp">

    </textview></linearlayout>
    <linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    </linearlayout>

</linearlayout>

<tablelayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchcolumns="*">
    <tablerow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingtop="50dp">
    <button android:id="@+id/btnSimple" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ListView From DB" android:textsize="25sp" android:layout_marginleft="10px" android:layout_marginright="10px" android:layout_marginbottom="5px" android:layout_margintop="5px" android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"></button>

</tablerow>
<tablerow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingtop="50dp">

</tablerow>

</tablelayout>
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you please post your complete stack trace?

Comment: just change your spelling <linearlayout> into <LinearLayout> make sure spellings for every xml elements

Answer (score 3):

> Yes because Tags are wrong

`linearlayout` this should be `LinearLayout`

`textview`  this should be `TextView`

`tablerow` this should be `TableRow`

`tablelayout` this should be `TableLayout`

> Try to learn about Android basics about layout

And also remove namespace for the second LinearLayout i.e remove this `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` for the child `LinearLayout`